# How can I insert another level of key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I want to modify the key to "inject" another level of dictionary.

For example:

Existing Dictionary

```
{
    "KeyA": "cat",
    "KeyB": "dog",
    "KeyD": "hat"
}
```

The result I want:

```
{
    "KeyD": "hat",
    "NewKey": {
        "KeyA": "cat",
        "KeyB": "dog"
    }
}
```

I have another dictionary which its key is the new key we want to insert and its value is a list of the affected keys in the existing dictionary.

```
affected_keys = {'NewKey': ['KeyA', 'KeyB']}
```

What I've tried is the following.

```
updated_dict = {insertKey(k, v): v for k, v in mydict.items()}

def insertKey(k, v):
    for j, l in affected_keys.items():
        if k in l:
            print(k + ' matched need to add subkey ' + j)
            #NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE
            nk = {}
            nk[j] = {}

    return nk
```

The error I get:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

If it is not possible doing it this way, could someone please suggest another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's simpler if you iterate over the changes rather than the input dict:

```
def transform(dct, affected_keys):
    new_dct = dct.copy()
    for new_key, keys in affected_keys.items():
        new_dct[new_key] = {key: new_dct.pop(key) for key in keys}
    return new_dct
```

Test case:

```
>>> transform({"KeyA": "cat", "KeyB": "dog", "KeyD": "hat"}, {"NewKey": ["KeyA", "KeyB"]})
{'KeyD': 'hat', 'NewKey': {'KeyA': 'cat', 'KeyB': 'dog'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you avoid iterating over the dictionary as it's being changed, it's relatively simple to do:

```
def inject_key_level(a_dict, new_keys):
    new_key = list(new_keys.keys())[0]
    new_keys = set(new_keys[new_key])  # To speed-up membership testing.
    new_level = {k: a_dict.pop(k) for k,v in list(a_dict.items()) if k in new_keys}
    a_dict[new_key] = new_level


my_dict = {
    "KeyA": "cat",
    "KeyB": "dog",
    "KeyD": "hat"
}

new_keys = {'NewKey': ['KeyA', 'KeyB']}

inject_key_level(my_dict, new_keys)
print(my_dict)  # -> {'KeyD': 'hat', 'NewKey': {'KeyA': 'cat', 'KeyB': 'dog'}}
```